# How to use Python to get a file's "last accessed" time the way Windows defines it?

Tags: python, windows, file, time

I'm trying to use Python to get a file's "last accessed" time according to Windows, which is basically the last time anything was done with the file, including e.g. copying or renaming. But Python's getatime() apparently only counts the last time a file was actually viewed or modified, which doesn't work for me. Is there any library or anything I could use for that?

If it matters, the problem I'm trying to solve is to get the exact order of files in which they were placed in a folder. Some were downloaded, and some might have been cut-and-pasted from anothe folder, in which case they'd keep the original file's creation time (that's why getctime() doesn't work for this, sadly).

Comment: Have you tried `getmtime()`?

Comment: Yep, but it only seems to consider the last time the file itself was modified, so it didn't work sadly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code snippet.

```
import os
import stat
import time


def get_file_event_time():
    filePath = '/path/to/file.extention'
    print("**** Get File Last Access time using os.stat() ****")
    # get the the stat_result object
    fileStatsObj = os.stat ( filePath )
    # Get last access time
    accessTime = time.ctime ( fileStatsObj [ stat.ST_ATIME ] )
    print("File Last Access Time : " + accessTime)
    print("**** Get File Creation time using os.stat() *******")
    # get the the stat_result object
    fileStatsObj = os.stat ( filePath )
    # Get the file creation time
    creationTime = time.ctime ( fileStatsObj [ stat.ST_CTIME ] )
    print("File Creation Time : " + creationTime)

    print("**** Get File Last Access time using os.path.getatime() ****")
    # Get last access time of file in seconds since epoch
    accessTimesinceEpoc = os.path.getatime(filePath)
    # convert time sinch epoch to readable format
    accessTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(accessTimesinceEpoc))
    print("File Last Access Time : " + accessTime)
    print("**** Get File Last Access time using os.path.getatime() in UTC Timezone****")
    accessTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(accessTimesinceEpoc))
    print("File Last Access Time : " + accessTime + ' UTC'  )
    print("**** Get File creation time using os.path.getctime() ****")
    # Get file creation time of file in seconds since epoch
    creationTimesinceEpoc = os.path.getctime(filePath)
    # convert time sinch epoch to readable format
    creationTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(creationTimesinceEpoc))
    print("File Creation Time : " + creationTime )
    print("**** Get File creation time using os.path.getctime() in UTC Timezone ****")
    creationTime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(creationTimesinceEpoc))
    print("File Creation Time : ", creationTime , ' UTC'  )


get_file_event_time()
```